# Name this polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

Tags: polynomials, terminology

What is the name for the monic polynomial of order $n$ where all $n+1$ terms have coefficient of $1$? i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$. Is it something like elementary monic polynomial?

---

For some reason I am asked to provide contexts for the terminology of a clearly defined polynomial. I know of [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). However that involves multiple variables but my question is monic.

This is also the partial sum of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but my question does not require $|x| < 1$.

Comment: It must be $x^k$.

Comment: @kmitov yes, of course, thanks

Comment: You can call the polynomial whatever you like, maybe Sarah or Bob ;) Jokes aside, I am not aware that it has a special name. Why do you think it should have one? Your name is quite entertaing, by the way

Comment: Finite monic geometric series? There probably isn’t a common name for it, but that is one posssible name.

Comment: The (ordinary) generating function for a sequence of $n + 1$ $1$s?

Comment: It's a polynomial whose roots are all $n+1$'th root of unity excluding $1$

Comment: If someone said “elementary monic polynomial,” I’d think $x^n,$ not something else.

Comment: When $\,n+1\,$ is a prime this is the $\,(n+1)^{th}\,$ [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Examples).

Comment: The name of this polynomial is $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @markvs sure, that's the same concept as the roots of unity comment above. I just thought since we have oeis and name for all sorts of sequences, it's not too wild to ask for the nomenclature of a polynomial.

Comment: You can call it the *Alexander-Leibowitz* polynomial or simply *AL*.